# Instance variable in Spree Custom Controller - automagically assigned?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I am new in Spree (and in Rails to be honest).

So I study a code(a spree custom conroller).
The controller definition looks like this:

```
module Spree
  module Admin
    class OneTimeLinksController < ResourceController
      def new
        super
        .....
        .....
```

In that controller there is a method called upon request.  The method name is `clicks_index`. The method looks like this:

```
     def clicks_index

        if params[:id]
          @one_time_link_clicks = @one_time_link.one_time_link_clicks.order(expires_at: :asc).paginate(page: params[:page] || 1, per_page: 30)
        end

     end
```

What puzzle me is where is this instance variable `@one_time_link`assigned a value?

I searched in the project didn't find anything. No before action in the controller.

And I wonder if Spree (or may be Rails) with its implicit functionality does't assign it a value - hidden from the reader/developer.

The request path is

**/admin/one_time_links/3/users**

and the route is

```
Spree::Core::Engine.routes.draw do
  namespace :admin do
    get 'one_time_links/:id/users' => 'one_time_links#clicks_index'
    .....
```

When I comment out all the code in the controller method `clicks_index`, I still see in the console that it loads bunch of Spree Models:

```
2019-11-15 18:27:24 +0200 1573835244279 (7306)   Spree::Order Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  `spree_orders`.* FROM `spree_orders` WHERE `spree_orders`.`completed_at` IS NULL AND `spree_orders`.`currency` = 'USD' AND `spree_orders`.`guest_token` = 'xxxxxxxxxx' AND `spree_orders`.`store_id` = 1 LIMIT 1
2019-11-15 18:27:24 +0200 1573835244288 (7306)   Spree::Order Load (1.9ms)  SELECT  `spree_orders`.* FROM `spree_orders` WHERE `spree_orders`.`user_id` = 1 AND `spree_orders`.`store_id` = 1 AND `spree_orders`.`completed_at` IS NULL ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1
2019-11-15 18:27:24 +0200 1573835244343 (7306)   Spree::LineItem Load (1.4ms)  SELECT `spree_line_items`.* FROM `spree_line_items` WHERE `spree_line_items`.`order_id` = 83166 ORDER BY `spree_line_items`.`created_at` ASC
2019-11-15 18:27:24 +0200 1573835244374 (7306)   Spree::Variant Load (1.5ms)  SELECT `spree_variants`.* FROM `spree_variants` WHERE `spree_variants`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `spree_variants`.`id` = 135
2019-11-15 18:27:24 +0200 1573835244403 (7306)   Spree::Image Load (1.8ms)  SELECT `spree_assets`.* FROM `spree_assets` WHERE `spree_assets`.`viewable_type` = 'Spree::Variant' AND `spree_assets`.`type` IN ('Spree::Image') AND `spree_assets`.`viewable_id` = 135 ORDER BY `spree_assets`.`position` ASC
2019-11-15 18:27:24 +0200 1573835244412 (7306)   Spree::OptionValueVariant Load (1.6ms)  SELECT `spree_option_value_variants`.* FROM `spree_option_value_variants` WHERE `spree_option_value_variants`.`variant_id` = 135
2019-11-15 18:27:24 +0200 1573835244423 (7306)   Spree::Product Load (1.4ms)  SELECT `spree_products`.* FROM `spree_products` WHERE `spree_products`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `spree_products`.`id` = 125
2019-11-15 18:27:25 +0200 1573835245089 (7306)   Spree::OneTimeLink Load (1.2ms)SELECT  `spree_one_time_links`.* FROM `spree_one_time_links` WHERE `spree_one_time_links`.`id` = 3 LIMIT 1
```

THIS ^^^^ ONE - the last line of the I think fills the variable

So it probably

Comment: It's worth searching for `instance_variable_set` throughout the codebase too

Comment: Also search the controller you inherit from and any in that inheritance chain starting with `ResourceController`

Comment: @Mark it comes from Spree https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/backend/app/controllers/spree/admin/resource_controller.rb

Comment: Searched `instance_variable_set`  `@one_time_link=` `@one_time_link =`, but nothing :(

Comment: It happens on line 130 of the file that you linked :)

Comment: @Mark thanks I would accept this as an answer if you suggest one ;)

Gosh, where can I read something about this inheritance chain method invocation in Ruby/Rails? It seems that before_action is inherently invoked.

Comment: http://rmulhol.github.io/ruby/2015/04/27/solid-rails.html looks like it has some good info